# Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate not updating the document

Tags: typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose, crud

Been trying to use Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate to update the document by ID, the operation runs without error but change is not reflected on database.

on server log i can only see  users.findOne logged when I run the API, shouldn't mongoose run update along with it aswell. I can get/create/delete user without any issue.

interface

```
export interface User {
  _id: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}
```

model

```
const userSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});
```

controller

```
public updateUser = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
      const userId: string = req.params.id;
      const userData: CreateUserDto = req.body;
      const updateUserData: User = await this.userService.updateUser(userId, userData);

      res.status(200).json({ data: updateUserData, message: 'updated' });
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  };
```

service

```
  public async updateUser(userId: string, userData: CreateUserDto): Promise<User> {
    if (isEmpty(userData)) throw new HttpException(400, "You're not userData");

    if (userData.email) {
      const findUser: User = await this.users.findOne({ email: userData.email });
      if (findUser && findUser._id != userId) throw new HttpException(409, `You're email ${userData.email} already exists`);
    }

    if (userData.password) {
      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(userData.password, 10);
      userData = { ...userData, password: hashedPassword };
    }

    const updateUserById: User = await this.users.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: userId }, { userData }, { new: true });
    if (!updateUserById) throw new HttpException(409, "You're not user");

    return updateUserById;
  }
```

dtos

```
import { IsEmail, IsString } from 'class-validator';

export class CreateUserDto {
  @IsEmail()
  public email: string;

  @IsString()
  public password: string;
}
```

Log when I run the update API

```
mongodbexpress | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-23T05:19:26.698+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"Checkpointer","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1629695966:698802][1:0x7f5f10065700], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 664, snapshot max: 664 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 2092"}}
server    | Mongoose: users.findOne({ email: 'newemil@gmail.com' }, { projection: {} })
server    | Mongoose: users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("6122ae51d922ae0a85b85484") }, { new: true, projection: {} })
server    | 2021-08-23 05:19:27 info: PUT /users/6122ae51d922ae0a85b85484 200 75.025 ms -
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The update doesn't work because you are passing `{ userData }` as update parameter to `findOneAndUpdate()`. That equivalent to `{ userData: userData }` and not fit with your schema. To solve it, you just need to make a little change:

```
const updateUserById: User = await this.users.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: userId }, userData, { new: true });
```